# How can I use scoped_allocator_adaptor with a custom allocator (wrapped in a class) so that it can be unwrapped for some types but not STL containers?

Tags: c++, memory-management, template-specialization, c++20, allocator

I have no idea how to better word my question.

My understanding of `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` is that it would take the allocator instance passed to a container and use that for the construction of elements/containers constructed in the container via `emplace_back`, IF they require such an allocator argument).

I have the following, it's a bit lengthy, but it was the minimum I could make that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <concepts>

namespace custom_memory
{
    class CustomAllocator
    {
    public:
        CustomAllocator(const std::size_t sizeBytes,
                        void* const start)
        :
            m_sizeBytes(sizeBytes),
            m_usedBytes(0),
            m_start(start),
            m_current(start)
        {

        }

        void* Allocate(const std::size_t& numBytes,
                       const std::uintptr_t& alignment)
        {
            std::size_t space = m_sizeBytes - m_usedBytes;
            if(std::align(alignment, numBytes, m_current, space))
            {
                // the amount used for alignment
                m_usedBytes += (m_sizeBytes-m_usedBytes) - space;
                // the amount actually needed
                m_usedBytes += numBytes;

                void* address = m_current;

                m_current = reinterpret_cast<void*>(
                    reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(m_current) + numBytes);

                return address;
            }
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }

        void Free(void* const ptr)
        {
            // do nothing in this Allocator, but other derived types may
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            m_current = m_start;
            m_usedBytes = 0;
        }

        std::size_t GetSize() const { return m_sizeBytes; }

    protected:
        const std::size_t m_sizeBytes;
        std::size_t m_usedBytes;
        void* const m_start;
        void* m_current;
    };
    // many types derive from base CustomAllocator type

    // allows for my custom allocators to be used in STL containers
    template<typename T, typename Alloc>
    class STLAdaptor
    {
    public:

        typedef T value_type;


        STLAdaptor(Alloc* allocator)
        :
            m_allocator(allocator)
        {

        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* allocate(std::size_t n)
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>
                (m_allocator->Allocate(n * sizeof(T), alignof(T)));
        }

        constexpr void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
        {
            m_allocator->Free(p);
        }

        std::size_t MaxAllocationSize() const
        {
            return m_allocator->GetSize();
        }

    protected:
        Alloc* m_allocator;
    };

    template<typename T, typename Allocator>
    using vector = std::vector<T,
        std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<STLAdaptor<T, Allocator>>>;
}

// overloads of global new and delete so I can use them with
// my custom allocators
void* operator new(std::size_t size, custom_memory::CustomAllocator& allocator,
                   std::uintptr_t alignment)
{
    return allocator.Allocate(size, alignment);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, custom_memory::CustomAllocator& allocator)
{
    allocator.Free(ptr);
}

// a type that needs an allocator for it's own internal use
template<typename A>
requires std::derived_from<A, custom_memory::CustomAllocator>
struct Foo
{
    A* m_allocator;
    int* m_foos;

    Foo(A* a)
    :
        m_allocator(a),
        m_foos(new (*a, alignof(int)) int(7))
    {

    }

    Foo(const Foo<A>& other)
    :
        m_allocator(other.m_allocator),
        m_foos(new (*m_allocator, alignof(int)) int(*(other.m_foos)))
    {

    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        operator delete (m_foos, *m_allocator);
    }

    Foo<A>& operator=(const Foo<A>& rhs)
    {
        m_allocator = rhs.m_allocator;
        *m_foos = *(rhs.m_foos);

        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::size_t memSize = 10000000;
    void* mem = std::malloc(memSize);

    typedef Foo<custom_memory::CustomAllocator> FooType;

    custom_memory::CustomAllocator customAlloc(memSize, mem);

    // this works
    {
        std::vector<FooType, custom_memory::STLAdaptor<FooType,
            custom_memory::CustomAllocator>>
            vec(&customAlloc);

        vec.emplace_back(&customAlloc);
    }

    // this works
    {
        custom_memory::vector<FooType,custom_memory::CustomAllocator>
            vec(&customAlloc);

        vec.emplace_back(&customAlloc); // <-- I don't want to pass this
    }

    // this doesn't work
    {
        custom_memory::vector<FooType,custom_memory::CustomAllocator>
            vec(&customAlloc);

        vec.emplace_back(); // <--- I thought scoped_allocator_adaptor
                            // would pass the allocator to constructed
                            // elements?
    }

    // this also doesn't work
    {
        typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
        custom_memory::STLAdaptor<char, custom_memory::CustomAllocator>>
        StringType;

        custom_memory::vector<StringType,custom_memory::CustomAllocator>
            vec(&customAlloc);

        vec.emplace_back("string");
    }

    std::free(mem);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a `CustomAllocator` that is derived from a base (not shown) and there's a bunch of different allocators derived from this base.

I have an `STLAdaptor` which allows that `CustomAllocator` to be used in STL containers. This is a templated class because of the many different allocators mentioned above (I actually have specialisations of `STLAdaptor` as well for the different allocators, not shown).

I've tried to `typedef` an `std::vector` which uses my `STLAdaptor` wrapped `CustomAllocator` within an `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`.

I then overload the global `new` and `delete` to accept a `CustomAllocator` to make the allocations.

Finally, I have a class that requires a `CustomAllocator` where internally it uses it to allocate memory for internal types (this is my use case).

You can see in my tests that I can:

1. Make an `std::vector` that successfully uses my `STLAdaptor` wrapped `CustomAllocator`. I can populate it with `Foo<CustomerAllocator>` types.
2. I can use my typedef of the `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` `std::vector`. But I need to explicitly pass the `CustomAllocator` instance to the internal type
3. I can't ommit it, but I would like to
4. I would like to also use other STL containers as well

I am pretty sure the problem is that `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` has an `STLAdaptor` allocator, not a `CustomAllocator`. But then I can't get it to work with an `std::string` either, but I think that has to do with the `STLAdaptor` having different types between the `std::vector` and the `std::string` (is this where `rebind` comes into play?

I am using GCC 10.2.0 and C++20

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to closely resemble `memory_resource` and `polymorphic_allocator`. Might not be a bad idea to take a look there.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am pretty sure the problem is that `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` has an `STLAdaptor` allocator, not a `CustomAllocator`.

That's correct as far as it goes. `scoped_allocator_adaptor` is going to pass down what it has, not some other type it doesn't know about.

Additionally, `scoped_allocator_adaptor` will use `uses_allocator` to determine if the type uses the allocator. That trait defaults to looking at whether the type defines a member type `allocator_type` to which the allocator can be converted.

> But then I can't get it to work with an `std::string` either, but I think that has to do with the `STLAdaptor` having different types between the `std::vector` and the `std::string` (is this where `rebind` comes into play?

Correct. `STLAdaptor` doesn't meet [the allocator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

Comment: Can you be more specific in how `STLAdaptor` does not meet allocator requirements? My understanding on `std::allocator_traits` is that it would provide defaults for everything I don't specify, and those defaults appear to be correct for `STLAdaptor`

Comment: Mixed-type construction, == and !=

Comment: What is mixed-type construction? I shouldn't need to provide `==` and `! =` because `std::allocator_traits` will default `::is_always_equal` to `std::false_type`

Comment: Where on that page does it say a false `is_always_equal` means you don't need to provide `==` and `!=`? (We might conceivably allow you to omit that when `is_always_equal` is true, but we don't even do that.) Mixed-type construction is the `A a(b)` part.

Comment: Sorry, I read it to mean sort of the inverse of what it says (if they are not always equal then `==` is always false), my bad.